# Required field with sensible default

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Consider the following

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
class Model(BaseModel):
    required: str
```

This will make `required` a required field for `Model`, however, in the FastAPI autogenerated Swagger docs it will have an example value of "string".

How can I make a required field with a sensible default? If I make a model like

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
class Model(BaseModel):
    required: str = 'Sensible default'
```

Then the field `required` is no longer required, but it shows up with a sensible default in the docs. Is there an easy workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked into *why* the (pydantic) model representation within the openapi  version that ships with FastAPI leaves the asterisk out, but the field is ***definitely*** still required (try putting a null value, or anything other than string). This might just be an UI inconsistency.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Field() to set up those options and check.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
class Model(BaseModel):
    something: str # required, shows "string"
    something: str = None # not required, shows "string"
    something: str = Field(..., example="this is the default display") # required, shows example
    something: str = Field(None, example="Foobar") #not required, show example
```

There are a multitude of different parameters that Field() can validate against.